# django .filter (or any other manager function) to check if item is present in ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

```
class Barrack(models.Model):
    """
    ... many other fields ...
    """

    def how_many_helmets_for_this_user(self, user):
        helmets = self.helmet_set.filter(possessors__contains=user) # how do we do this?
        return helmets.count()

class Helmet(models.Model):
    barrack = models.ForeignKey(Barrack)
    possessors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

The code above doesn't works. The `__contains` filter is made only for strings. Yet, I'd like to filter all the helmets where `user` is in `helmet.possessors`.

I'd like to know if this is possible to do so **using exclusively Django's managers function**.

---

I already have a lousy and extremely inefficient solution which doesn't use Django's manager:

```
def how_many_helmets(self, user):
    result = 0
    helmets = self.helmet_set.all()
    for helmet in helmets:
        if helmet.is_user_in_possessors(user):
            result += 1
    return result

# in Helmet class
def is_user_in_possessors(self, user):
    for possessor in self.possessors.all():
        if possessor == user:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
helmets = self.helmet_set.filter(possessors=user)
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) you will find the relevant documentation for M2M relationships

Comment: This answer could use more explanation.